# Angular 2 Lazyloading depends on existing URL segements

Tags: angular

I want to lazyload a component which totally depends on the url given by the user. To be more precise it depends on the second url segment.

This is how I read the segment and then load the equivalent module.

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var segment = pathArray[2];

export const routes:Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component : DeskComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                loadChildren: "app/desk/" + segment + "/" + segment + ".module#" + (segment.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + segment.slice(1)) + "Module"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Now I know this is far from perfect. As this is a child route and the parent route actually passes the parameter segment `desk/:segment` I can subscribe in my component to *ActivatedRoute.params* and get the segment.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe((params: Params) => params['segment']);
}
```

Is it somehow possible that my child route waits for that param and adjusts it's route to it? I don't know how I can bring them together.

Comment: Would it be an option to pre-declare all possible paths during app initialization instead of calculating them at run-time?

Comment: @AngularFrance It would be an option. But as my path is empty and has no rule how would you choose which module to load?

Comment: Well, the way your routes are set up is a bit confusing. You did mention that what's lazy-loaded is based on URL segments. So is it *conceptually* correct to say you have some form of "path <==> module to load" mapping?

Comment: @AngularFrance Yes I understand. Here is my conflict: On the parent route I pass the param `:segment` which I need in my component. It is an important information for my data requests. So as I have already set the segment on my parent route I can't do it on my child route where I need decide which module refers to this segment. Otherwise I would have the route app/desk/:segment/:segment … a repetition. Is this comprehensible? That's why I have left the path blank.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your route hierarchy.

Wouldn't it be possible to pre-declare all possible routes like so:

```ts
const segments = ['foo', 'bar'];
export const routes: Routes = [];

let capitalizedSegment = segment.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + segment.slice(1);
for (let segment of segments) {
  routes.push({
    path: `some/path/${segment}`
    loadChildren: `app/desk/${segment}/${segment}.module#${capitalizedSegment}Module`
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @AngularFrance. That is definitively a good solution for the problem. I have found another way to setup my routes and still keep my child configuration (outlets and params).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I stripped out the routes from my child module and defined all routes in the parent module.

I didn't know that I still can keep my router outlets in my child module. I thought they also need a route configuration. But that's not the case! So I can keep my system in my child module without any route configuration.